# Symmetric Key Generation

Tags: java, jce

I have two questions:

1. When to use `SecretKeySpec` and when to use `KeyGenerator` for key generation?
2. Is it necessary that the Key instance and the Cipher instance has to follow the same Algorithm? What is the concept behind?

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on your application
2. Yes.  Different ciphers may use different key lengths.  You pass AlgorithmParameterSpec to the key generator.

Comment: Thanks stark, but for question1 , what would be the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

`KeyGenerator` creates a *new* random key each time it is called. The returned key is also guaranteed to have the length compatible with the algorithm specified when obtaining the `KeyGenerator` instance.

`SecretKeySpec` wraps an *existing* byte array. The source of bytes can be a hex or Base64 string or really any other textual or binary representation of the previously generated key. Hence the use case for `SecretKeySpec` is when you need to reuse the key which was previously stored in some external representation.

Usually an instance of `SecretKeySpec` can be used directly as a key because `SecretKeySpec` implements `SecretKey` and most crypto algorithms that use secret keys support so-called "raw" keys where the "raw" key is basically a random sequence of bytes without specific internal structure.

When an algorithm requires a specific `SecretKey` representation (usually a subclass of `SecretKey` internal to algorithm implementation) you will have to use `SecretKeyFactory` to transform a `SecretKeySpec` into a proper `SecretKey`.

If a crypto algorithm supports "raw" keys then the only requirement is that the key length matches the algorithm expectations.

But the implementer of crypto provider can decide that he needs to use a specific key representation which, for example, caches or precalculates some values based on the initial "raw" bytes. In that case the algorithm can require that a `SecretKey` instance passed into in addition to returning correct identifiers from `Key.getAlgorithm()` and `Key.getFormat()` methods is also a specific subclass of `SecretKey`, so the usage of `SecretKeyFactory` to convert key spec into a key is mandatory. Such cases are usually documented in the provider documentation.